# MAMP PDO_MySql error with Zend2 and Doctrine2

Tags: mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm, mamp

I have propobly problem with PDO_MySql in my Zend2 & Doctrine project...
This is my error, when i try use doctrine:
http://wklej.to/PX5RW

I use MAMP.

This is my php.ini:
http://wklej.to/DMUXi

This is my connection setup:

`'connection' => array(
            // default connection name
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '3306',
                    'user'     => 'root',
                    'password' => 'root',
                    'dbname'   => 'project',
                )
            )
        )`

I realy don't now what can be wrong... Can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having similar problems, one of the best bits of advice I've received is that your cli version of PHP may not be using the correct version.

In terminal type php --ini and if the location of that doesn't point to your mamp folder. Follow the instructions listed here:

http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/getting-command-line-access-php-and-mysql-running-mamp-osx